# Unable to trigger angular ng-change function, when dropdown is automated in Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, dom-events

```html
<select class="form-control ng-pristine" ng-model="conf.pinnedOriginalTransaction.net" name="categoryId" style="width:90%;" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in categoryIdList" ng-change="validateForAction()" required="">..
```

I have faced a situation where in my form when a certain value is selected from a drop-down list only, the button I need to click gets enabled.
This work when fine when done manually, But when the Select webelement is automated, although desired value gets selected, angular js function that enables button does not get triggered.

As per my research on this, I managed to write code to manually trigger the function JS ScriptExecutor, but still getting a Null Pointer exception. The automated code is given below.

```js
Select dropdown = new Select(webelement);
                log.info(webelement);
                dropdown.selectByVisibleText(sValue);
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].validateForAction(true);",webelement);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to ensure all `pendingRequests` are completed.

You can use this JS for that:

```
var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector();
var $http = injector.get('$http');
return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0);
```

Hope this helps you!